# InvalidOperationException when serializing [Flags] enum with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, asp.net, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize an `enum` type that is decorated with `[Flags]` attribute. The `enum` declaration is as follows:

```
[Flags]
[ProtoContract(EnumPassthru = true)]
public enum Categories
{
    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(Invalid), Value = 0x0)]
    Invalid = 0x0,

    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(A), Value = 0x1)]
    A = 0x1,
    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(B), Value = 0x2)]
    B = 0x2,
    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(C), Value = 0x4)]
    C = 0x4,
    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(D), Value = 0x8)]
    D = 0x8,
    [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(Global), Value = 0x1 | 0x2 | 0x4 | 0x8)]
    Global = A | B | C | D,
}
```

Now, when I try to serialize the container object, I get

> InvalidOperationException:Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Following other similar posts on SO, I have tried the following:

1. Add `EnumPassthru = true` parameter in my enum's ProtoContract attribute
2. Use `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Categories)].EnumPassthru = true;` at the app startup phase,
3. Provided the container object's enum-valued field with the IsRequired parameter `[ProtoMember(6, IsRequired = true)]`

Is there anything else that I miss with my enum declaration?

The beginning of the exception detail goes like:

> InvalidOperationException:Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.\r\n   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.EnumSerializer.EnumToWire(Object value) in c:\Users\onur.gumus\Desktop\protobuf-net-master\protobuf-net\Serializers\EnumSerializer.cs:line 83\r\n   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.EnumSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Users\onur.gumus\Desktop\protobuf-net-master\protobuf-net\Serializers\EnumSerializer.cs:line 125\r\n   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.FieldDecorator.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Users\onur.gumus\Desktop\protobuf-net-master\protobuf-net\Serializers\FieldDecorator.cs:line 38\r\n   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.Write(Object value, ProtoWriter dest) in c:\Users\onur.gumus\Desktop\protobuf-net-master\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 173\r\n   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TrySerializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoWriter writer, Type type, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Object value, Boolean isInsideList) in c:\Users\onur.gumus\Desktop\protobuf-net-master\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 125 ...

Comment: What *exact* version of protobuf-net is this? I tried your code in the current nuget release and it worked fine; I tried it removing all the attributes except `[Flags]` and it worked fine. Also, are you using any particular / unusual framework here? I've tried 2.3.0 and 2.0.0.668 - both worked fine

Answer (score 0):

In all easily available (i.e. not ancient) versions of protobuf-net, `[Flags]` will activate pass-thru behaviour, making this work fine. `[ProtoContract(EnumPassThru = true)]` will *also* activate pass-thru behaviour, but is redundant if `[Flags]` is specified.

In 2.3.0 and above, pass-thru behaviour is also *assumed by default* as long as you don't have any `[ProtoEnum]` attributes that *actually change the serialized value* (which: yours do not) - this is to be more consistent with "proto3", and to make it easier to work with enums in the vast majority of cases.

So: it should not be necessary to do *anything* here - your code should already just work.

I've tried your code:

- with 2.3.0 and 2.0.0.668
- with the attributes in the question, and with everything except `[Flags]` removed
- on 2.3.0 with even the `[Flags]` attribute removed (although I agree it should be retained in your case - that is definitely a `[Flags]` enum)
- with the enum as the root value, and with the enum as a member marked `[ProtoMember]` on an object passed in

In all cases it worked fine. So: *in the general case*, all I can say is that what you have *should already work*.

If it is failing in a *specific* case, it would be great to include a full runnable sample in the question (ideally telling us exactly what framework you are running on), so we can see what you are seeing. This works fine, for example:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;

[Flags]
public enum Categories
{
    Invalid = 0x0,
    A = 0x1,
    B = 0x2,
    C = 0x4,
    D = 0x8,
    Global = A | B | C | D,
}
[ProtoContract]
public class X
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Categories Val { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Val.ToString();
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var orig = new X { Val = Categories.D | Categories.B };
        var cloneObj = Serializer.DeepClone(orig);
        Console.WriteLine(cloneObj);

        var cloneEnum = Serializer.DeepClone(orig.Val);
        Console.WriteLine(cloneEnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: "In all easily available (i.e. not ancient) versions of protobuf-net"
well this explains everything:)
my project's client part is a xamarin.ios app. installing the standard protobuf-net package on xamarin asked me to install a dozen or so packages as well. then I decided to use protobuf-portable-net and I also installed it on the backend project just in order to be on par with the client. now the server code runs perfectly, but I should find a feasible solution for the client too :)
@marc-gravell

Comment: @Ugur ah, right; where exactly did you get this DLL? I might be able to help, though; does your xamarin target work with .net standard at all? I could possibly try a xamarin specific build, but I don't have that today

Comment: firstly, thanks a lot for your interest!
I downloaded both packages via Nuget. the standard one, called "protobuf-net" is the up-to-date one and it' the one that solved the server-side problem.
Xamarin.iOS version is 10.10 - the latest one. I guess I mixed up the installation problem of protobuf-net with something else - sorry for that. Nuget error message on xamarin is "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework" @marc-gravell

Comment: @Ugur I need to dust off my xamarin tooling knowledge... 10.10 you say? I'll see what I can find out

Comment: yes. you can see the version history at this link [link](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) it is shown once you click "View all versions"

Comment: @MarcGravell We're also experiencing the exact same thing using protobuf-net 2.0.0.668 in a UWP project, and none of the potential workarounds have worked. Any other ideas of what's going on?